# How to fix "The import org.mockito cannot be resolved"?

Tags: java, mockito

I have a maven project in which there is a class called - BookingServiceTest.java where i tried importing 
org.mockito.InjectMocks
org.mockito.Mock
org_mockito_Mockito and
org_mockito_MockitoAnnotations. But i got the error - "The import org_mockito cannot be resolved"

Can anyone suggest how can we resolve this?

jar used: mockito-all-1.9.5.jar added to my local maven repository.

Comment: It seems your replaced dots with underscores in some package names, try `org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations`  and `org.mockito.Mockito`  instead.

Answer (score 14):

In Project, Go to:
**Build Path** --> **Configuration Path**,

In **Java Build Path**, Go to:
**Source**

In both directories ***src/test/java*** and ***src/test/resource***, set:

**Output folder**: to a separate target fold different from the default target fold, 
for example: target/test-classes

**Contain Test Resources**: Yes

Comment: Contain Test Resources: Yes - worked for me, Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to import the wrong packages

This is what should be in your `pom.xml` file under `dependencies`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And simple test should look like this

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class InjectMocksTest {

@Mock
private ClassB classB;
@InjectMocks
private ClassA classA;

@Test
public void test() {
    Mockito.doReturn("Hi").when(classB).message();

    Assert.assertEquals("Hi David!", classA.greeting("David"));

}

private static class ClassA {

    private final ClassB classB;

    private ClassA(ClassB classB) {
        this.classB = classB;
    }

    public String greeting(String name) {
        return classB.message() + " " + name + "!";
    }
}

private static class ClassB {
    public String message() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

}